# ¿Cómo guardar los caracteres especiales o alfanuméricos de un String en un ArrayList?

Tags: java

> De una variable String cuyo texto es ingresado por el usuario, hacer un programa que de la variable saque las letras de a-z y lo guarde en un String nuevo, lo mismo con los caracteres numéricos y especiales.

Ejemplo:

`String var = "abc123!";`

***Muestra en pantalla:***

```
texto solo letras: abc
texto caracteres especiales: 123!
```

¿Debo usar `ArrayList`?

¿Cómo le indico al lenguaje que si `texto.CharAt(i)!="[^a-zA-Z]";`
guarde ese caracter o letra en una variable?

Sé que `[a-z]` es del método `String#matches`.

¿Cómo manejo los caracteres para que si el del `CharArray(i)` es letra lo mande a la variable? (sé que debo usar `ArrayList`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No es Necesario Usar `ArrayList`** Sí deseas obtener las letras en una variable y lo demás en otra, tendrías la opción de usar el método [replaceAll(String regex,String replacement)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String var = "1abc1-_<+zsa_.2**¿2!%/&=??}{}+´;:,-m3!54";
    String numeros= var.replaceAll("\\D+","");
    String letras = var.replaceAll("[\\W0-9_]","");
    String especial = var.replaceAll("[0-9a-zA-Z0-9]","");

    System.out.println("texto solo numeros:  " + numeros);
    System.out.println("texto solo letras:  " + letras);
    System.out.println("texto caracteres especiales:  " + especial);
}
```

O Mediante un for , validando con el método [isDigit(char arg)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char)) para verificar si es un número , [isLetter(char arg)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(char)) para validar si es letra, y caso contrario será caracteres especiales. todo esto concatenando con la variable respectiva.

```
    String var = "1abc1-_<+zsa_.2**¿2!%/&=??}{}+´;:,-m3!54";
    String numeros="",letras="",otros="";
    for (char arg : var.toCharArray()) {
        if(Character.isDigit(arg))
            numeros+=arg;
        else if(Character.isLetter(arg))
            letras+=arg;
        else
            otros+=arg;
    }
    System.out.println(numeros);
    System.out.println(letras);
    System.out.println(otros);
```

Si es necesario usar `ArrayList`, sería algo similar.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String var = "1abc1-_<+zsa_.2**¿2!%/&=??}{}+´;:,-m3!54";
    ArrayList<String> letras = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> otros = new ArrayList<>();
for (char arg : var.toCharArray()) {
    if(Character.isDigit(arg))
        numeros.add(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(arg)));
    else if(Character.isLetter(arg))
        letras.add(String.valueOf(arg));
    else
        otros.add(String.valueOf(arg));
 }
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letras.toArray()));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numeros.toArray()));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(otros.toArray()));
}
```

Comment: Si usas `ArrayList`, dos cosas: 1) Definir la variable como `List` para alentar el uso de interfaces antes que de clases concretas. 2) Sería mejor usar `List<Character>` así no necesitarías convertir el caracter ni a `String` ni a `Integer`. Y en el caso de `List<Integer>` en particular, podría ser `List<Byte>`.